# Assistance with PAC file Configuration for Bypassing Teams and Client IP

Tags: proxy, pac

I am trying to use a PAC file to route home/VPN users through their home ISP, when using Teams. I have a basic understanding of PAC files, but struggling to implement a more complex requirement like this.

Essentially, I need to evaluate two parameters, source IP and destination URL, and if matched, go DIRECT, which i assume will be the users ISP.

Does my concept make sense, is the configuration possible in a PAC file, and also will 'DIRECT' actually use the ISP. Does DIRECT effectively just use default gateway?

Thanks all.
D

Comment: Resolved:if ((
        (isInNet(myIpAddress(), "192.168.0.1", "255.255.255.0")) ||  // Client subnets
        (isInNet(myIpAddress(), "192.168.1.0", "255.255.255.0")) && 
        (
        shExpMatch(host, "*.lync.com") || 
        shExpMatch(host, "*.mail.protection.outlook.com") ||
        shExpMatch(host, "*.manage.office.com") ||
        shExpMatch(host, "*.msftidentity.com") ||

Comment: if ((
        (isInNet(myIpAddress(), "192.168.0.1", "255.255.255.0")) ||  // These two lines needs to be completed with subnet that is actually 
        (isInNet(myIpAddress(), "192.168.1.0", "255.255.255.0")) &&  // intended for split tunnel in pac file. 
        (
        shExpMatch(host, "*.lync.com") || 
        shExpMatch(host, "*.mail.protection.outlook.com") ||
        shExpMatch(host, "*.manage.office.com") ||
        shExpMatch(host, "*.msftidentity.com") ||